# MonoGame WP custom vertex decleration

Tags: xna, c#, monogame, vertex, windows-phone-8

How do I go about implementing and using a custom vertex deceleration in monogame for windows phone 8. I want to be able to store a position, a colour and a normal?

Comment: Have you accomplished this with XNA since you used it as a tag?  It's the same process.

Comment: As I understand it monogame is supposed to work the same as xna 4.0, but I have bot managed it on xna yet though

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46518/custom-vertexdeclaration-for-color-texture-normal

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a cross breed of the following two tutorials:

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_lighting.php

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976065(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx